# Importar arquivo no TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf

Estou personalizando um contrato em `TCPDF`.

Consegui fazer funcionar as informações sobre as partes, mas a parte das cláusulas deste contrato, está complicado.

Queria fazer as cláusulas em um outro arquivo e depois chamar este arquivo para fazer parte do contrato, tipo:

```
MultiCell(0,5, ./clausula.php, 0, 'J');
```

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: `MultiCell(0,5, file_get_contents('./clausula.php'), 0, 'J');` ou ao invés do `file_get_contents` pode ser o `include`.

Comment: Tentei usando file_get_contents(), e ele importa o código, tags e cláusulas, Eu quero que importe só cláusulas formatada. Tentei usar o include, mas não consegui, Desculpe sou novato.